# MySQL statement that returns users inbox - SELECT conversation, user, name, last message FROM 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, json, rest, phpmyadmin

I am making a statement that will return a string of data to display a users inbox just by inputting their `user_id`.

I have three tables: users, conversations, and messages. I am trying to make a SQL statement that will return the `conv_id`, `user_id`, name (from users table), and the last message sent in that conversation. So far this is the statement I came up with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.conversation AS conv_id, n.user_id, n.name, n.message_body FROM
    (SELECT CONCAT(u.first, " ", u.last) AS name, c.conv_id AS conversation, c.user_id, m.message_body
    FROM users AS u,
      (SELECT conv_id, CASE
        WHEN user1="14" THEN user2
        WHEN user2="14" THEN user1
        END AS user_id FROM conversations) AS c,
      (SELECT DISTINCT x.id, x.message_body, x.conv_id FROM messages AS x,
        (SELECT conv_id AS convs FROM conversations WHERE user1="14" or user2="14") AS y
      WHERE (x.message_from="14" or x.message_to="14") AND x.conv_id=y.convs
      ORDER by x.id DESC) AS m
    WHERE u.user_id=c.user_id) as n
  GROUP BY n.conversation
```

And as of right now it returns the `conversation`, `user_id`, and `name` I am looking for but it is giving me the wrong `message_body` for each conversation.

My tables look like this:

users

```
user_id | first | last
14        John    Smith
15        Steve   Lowe
16        Will    Willis
```

conversations

```
conv_id | user1 | user2
4         14     15
5         15     16
6         16     14
```

messages

```
id | conv_id | message_to | message_from | message_body
1    4         15           14             alpha
2    4         14           15             beta
3    4         15           14             charlie
4    4         14           15             delta
5    5         16           15             epsilon
6    5         15           16             foxtrot
7    5         16           15             golf
8    5         15           16             hotel
9    6         14           16             india
10   6         16           14             juliette
11   6         14           16             kilo
12   6         16           14             lima
```

For `user_id` = 14 I want my statement to return:

```
conv_id | user_id |     name     | message_body
4        15        Steve Lowe     delta
6        16        Will Willis    lima
```

It's a really tough query to figure out. Maybe I need to try using a join.

Please help!

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70359d

Comment: Yes, you need to learn joins and they are needed for this and many other SQL related solutions.

Comment: "And as of right now it returns the conversation, user_id, and name I am looking for but it is giving me the wrong message_body for each conversation." [You are misusing MySQL extended GROUP BY feature](https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/)

Comment: it looks like you want the latest id records within the group conv_id where message_id = 14? i assume the id column has a primary key and a auto_increment option?

Comment: Can we have a sqlfiddle?

Comment: why the JSON tag? You sure you didn't mean to use JOIN instead?

Comment: Here is the sqlfiddle: [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70359d)

Answer (score 0):

This is one is working for me for now

```
SELECT CONCAT(u.first, " ", u.last) AS name, m.conv_id, c.user_id, m.message_body, m.sent_time
    FROM users AS u, 
    (SELECT conv_id, CASE WHEN user1="14" THEN user2 WHEN user2="14" 
    THEN user1 END AS user_id FROM conversations) AS c, 
    (SELECT MAX(id), conv_id, message_body, sent_time FROM messages 
    WHERE message_to="14" or message_from="14" GROUP BY conv_id ORDER BY 
    sent_time DESC) AS m
WHERE u.user_id=c.user_id AND m.conv_id=c.conv_id
```